# Copying a Range from one Sheet to Another with Variables

Tags: excel, vba, range

This is my code:

```
If AssociateNameArray(ArrayLoop) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(3, CompareCounter).Value Then
    If i = 2 Then
        Sheets(i).Range(CompareCounter & "6:" & CompareCounter & "12").Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range((ArrayLoop + 4) & "2")
        Sheets(i).Range(CompareCounter & "14:" & CompareCounter & "28").Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range((ArrayLoop + 4) & "9")
        CompareCounter = CompareCounter + 1
    End If
End If
```

It gives

> 1004 error

Basically I am walking through a set range where CompareCounter is the column number.  (stupid name, I know) I have names in an array and it is comparing the values of the array to cells in a row and when it finds a match it copies a set range back to the person's column on the main page at a certain row.  The person's column number should be ArrayLoop + 4, as they start in column E.  I will walk through each sheet (i) and when I find matches I will take the ranges from that sheet and copy it to the main page.

Comment: See how to make a [MCVE]. It is really important, that anyone would be able to copy and paste the code and see the same error. Then it would be easy to replicate and a good solution would be provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is what causes the 1004 error: `Range((ArrayLoop + 4) & "2")`

If `ArrayLoop` is 4, then once it is evaluated to something, then it looks like this `Range(52)` and this is no valid range, returning `1004`.

In general, try to debug the code step-by-step with <kbd>F8</kbd> and always look at the values of the variables.

Comment: I did use F8, but it kicked out right on this line and reset all my watched variables. Can I not set that operation inside the range function?  Do I need to add 4 to that variable outside the range function?

Comment: @Country_Gravy - Take a look at the Range object - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object). It should be something like `Range("A:" & (ArrayLoop + 4) & "2")` in order to be a valid one. E.g. once it is solved, it should be  `Range("A52")` or something valid.